# merging two lists positionally in Scheme

Tags: list, merge, tree, scheme, racket

## Example

First list: `(1 2 3 4)`

Second list: `(* slot (- slot (/ slot slot)))`

Output: `(* 1 (- 2 (/ 3 4)))`

The first list's elements will be inserted to the second list.

The symbol `slot` in second list means the position for insertion.

## My Solution

I have written a code snippet and it works for the above example.

```
(define (insert-slot numbers slots)
  (cond
    [(null? slots)
     '()]
    ;; operate on the nested list and come back to the element after
    [(pair? (car slots))
     (cons 
           (insert-slot numbers (car slots))     ;; nested list
           (insert-slot numbers (cdr slots)))]   ;; element after
    ;; insert number to slot
    [(equal? (car slots) 'slot)
     (cons (car numbers)
           (insert-slot (cdr numbers) (cdr slots)))]
    ;; just take the original element in slots
    (else
     (cons (car slots)
           (insert-slot numbers (cdr slots))))))
```

## Problem

However, the second clause(operate on the nested list) of the cond has some problems, the `numbers` used in the nested list and the element after should be different. The later `numbers` is the result of the previous `numbers`. It works correctly for the example above, but if the second list likes this `(* (+ slot slot) (- slot slot))`, it will get the wrong answer.

I figured out that I can store states in the `numbers` and return different value based on the times it has called, but it's not like the Scheme way(no extra stored data). Is there a simple way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TL;DR:* yes, with [continuation-passing](/questions/tagged/continuation-passing) style.

---

Very interesting question! Nested list is a *tree*, so you're merging a linear list of values  into a tree's *fringe*, according to the presence of a keyword `'slot`  there.

So we start, as is usual in structural recursions tasks, with traversing a tree to just create an exact copy of it, to get a hang of it,

```
(define (copy-tree tree)
    (cond
       [(not (pair? tree)) tree]                   ; return the leaf
       [else (cons (copy-tree (car tree))          ; combine results from car
                   (copy-tree (cdr tree)))]))      ;     and results from cdr
```

Next we linearize it by going [*CPS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style),

```
(define (copy-tree tree k)
    (cond
       [(not (pair? tree)) (k tree)]               ; "return" the leaf into k
       [else (copy-tree (car tree) (lambda (r)     ; collect results from car as r
               (copy-tree (cdr tree) (lambda (q)   ;  collect results from cdr as q
                 (k (cons r q))))))]))             ;   "return" combined r and q into k
```

and then we thread our state through, traversing the list of given values to substitute for each instance of the keyword:

```
(define (merge-tree-fringe vals tree keywd k)
  (cond
    [(not (pair? tree))                  ; for each leaf:
     (if (not (eq? tree keywd))          ; if it is not the keyword,
       (k vals tree)                     ;   "return" vals AND leaf into k, or
       (k (cdr vals) (car vals)))]       ;   USE the first of vals, if it is
    [else
     (merge-tree-fringe vals (car tree) keywd (lambda (Avals r)    ; collect from car,
      (merge-tree-fringe Avals (cdr tree) keywd (lambda (Dvals q)  ;  collect from cdr,
       (k Dvals (cons r q))))))]))       ; return the last vals and the combined results
```

We call it as

```
> (merge-tree-fringe '(1 2 3 4) 
                     '(* slot (- slot (/ slot slot))) 
                     'slot
                     (lambda (v r) r))
'(* 1 (- 2 (/ 3 4)))

> (merge-tree-fringe '(1 2 3 4) 
                     '(* (+ slot slot) (- slot slot))
                     'slot
                     (lambda (v r) r))
'(* (+ 1 2) (- 3 4))
```

This can be further cleaned up by adding error checking, and converting to an internal definition with shorter name and fewer arguments.

*edit:* In a pattern-matching pseudocode, which might be easier to read/follow, it is

```hs
merge-tree-fringe vals tree keywd = g vals tree (v r => r)
  where
  g vals [a, ...d] k = g vals a (avals r =>
                           g avals d (dvals q => 
                               k dvals [r, ...q]))
  g [v, ...vs] lf  k 
             | lf == keywd = k vs   v     -- use first value for a matching leaf
  g vals       lf  k       = k vals lf
```

This computational pattern of threading a changing state through the computations is exactly what (Haskell's) State monad is about; the above would be written there (sans the particulars of the "tree" type) as

```hs
merge_tree_fringe vals tree keywd = evalState (g tree) vals
    where
    g (a:d)            = do { r <- g a ; q <- g d ; return (r:q) }
    g lf | lf == keywd = do { (v:vs) <- get ; put vs ; return v }
         | otherwise   = do { return lf }
```

where the state - our "values" - is passed around as part of a "stateful computation pipeline" implicitly, with automatically correct sequencing (which we had to take care of manually, using the `avals` and `dvals` carefully each in its appropriate place in our Scheme code); and `evalState` performs this whole combined computation while discarding the end state, returning only the finally computed value just like our collector/continuation-function `(lambda (v r) r)` did.

Turning the latter into the former is a matter of a purely syntactic transformation. So it's nothing special, this "[monad](/questions/tagged/monad)" thing, after all. It's *a computational pattern*, explicated, captured.