# Haskell - Translate a list to a recursive data structure

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I found this problem in a Haskell textbook. Given a recursive data structure:

```
data Foo = A Foo Foo | B Int Foo | C Int
```

create a function:

```
createFooFromList :: [Int] -> Foo -> Foo
```

that takes in a list and a `Foo`, applies the list to the `Foo`, and returns the new `Foo`.

What "applying" means is best described using an example.

Say we have a `Foo` that is defined as `B 0 (B 1 (A (B 0 (C 1)) (B 1 (C 1))))` and we have to apply the list `[0,0,1,0,2,0]` to this `Foo`. To do this, simply take each integer in the given sequence and replace integers in the `Foo` structure in order with these integers in the sequence.

So for the above example, our output would be `B 0 (B 0 (A (B 1 (C 0)) (B 2 (C 0))))`

So far,  I have created a function that applies the list to the `B` and `C` structures. `C` is trivial, and `B` is also easy as I simply set the head of the list to the `Int` parameter of `B`, and recursively apply the rest of the list to the `Foo` part of `B`. However I am unsure as to how to deal with `A`.

Comment: where is 2 in the output?

Comment: Can you share what you have already done and where you are stuck? I would assume some kind of CPS approach, but this can be done in lots of ways.

Comment: What order? Breadth-first, depth-first, something else?

Comment: what if it's not possiblee "apply" the list?

Comment: @MartinKristiansen As I said in my question, I'm struggling with A. Right now my idea is that I would have some sort of secondary function that "scans" a certain path to find how many integers are in it, so that my algorithm can know how much of a list to supply to either Foo in A.

Comment: This is very similar to the tree-labelling problem described in the documentation for [`Control.Monad.Trans.Lazy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html).

Comment: well, firstly, `B Int Foo ==  A (C Int) Foo` so the data type is needlessly overly complex.

Comment: @MartinKristiansen yes, [CPS works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50588667/849891). it encodes state passing with [unique selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9889702/849891) from [shrinking domain](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+shrinking+domain). which is like parsing.

Comment: @chepner "Breadth-first, depth-first, something else?" not applicable. there's no data in nodes, only in leaves. the  intent is fringe replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint:

I would start by writing an auxiliary function, which takes the `[Int]` and `Foo` arguments, and returns not just the output `Foo` but an additional `[Int]` representing the numbers in the input list which have not been used, yet. 
Hence, the resulting output type can be a pair.

The intuition here is that this auxiliary function does not assume that the input `[Int]` list contains the right amount of numbers for the `Foo` input, but allows more `Int`s to be present, and returns the ones in excess.

Using this auxiliary function, you can handle the `A` case with two `Foo`s inside: you call the auxiliary function on the first `Foo`, and obtain the excess `Int`s, then you use those for the second `Foo`, and return the new excess `Int`s.

(A more advanced approach would be to use a `State [Int]` monad, but the above basic approach should be fine.)

Comment: Fun fact, the advanced approach and the basic one are the same